# What does List[:] = List do in this radix sort code?

Tags: python, sorting, radix

[What is wrong with my radix sort?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22844711/what-is-wrong-with-my-radix-sort)

Here is a link to a radix sort code i found. It works (the top answer's code) but my question is what does List[:] = [] do in this context (I know its meant for list splitting). I mean you suppose to reconstruct the list from the buckets after every iteration but when I change that line to List = [] the code stops working. Why is that so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following case, which is a small version of what you are trying to understand:

```
def foo(x):
    x = []
    x.append(1)
    print(x)

my_list = []
foo(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

You expect the function `foo` to clear the list it received as an argument and, afterward, modify it by appending the number `1`, right? Actually, that is not what happens...

```
>>> foo(my_list)
[1]
>>> print(my_list)
[]
```

Why so?

Because when you wrote `x = []`, instead of clearing the original list, you actually *changed the local variable `x` to refer to a new list*. On the other hand, `my_list` is still referring to the original list!

Now, let's try the same but using `x[:]` instead:

```
def foo(x):
    x[:] = []
    x.append(1)
    print(x)

my_list = []
foo(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

Now, everything should work as you expected:

```
>>> foo(my_list)
[1]
>>> print(my_list)
[1]
```

The `x[:]` trick is basically telling the interpreter to *replace the contents of the list referred by `x` by a new empty list*. Now, it is not `x` that will change to which list it is pointing to. In fact, it will still refer to the same list as `my_list` and, as a side effect, this will alter the original list.

In order to truly grasp what is going on behind the scenes, take a look at [how variables are passed by assignment in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference), specially if you aren't familiar with the concept of pointers.